# I am making a firebase-database list and don't know how to make it remove items from the database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am pretty new to Javascript, a couple of months in. Essentially, I am trying to make a simple online-based shared shopping-list for a class. I can add to the database, I can show the items as a list, right now my issue is how to remove. I have given the buttons the keys of the database entry they are attached to, as ID, hoping that that would work, but I can't find a way to use the ID. As you can see, i've been testing it by seeing if I can console.log the key, but no luck so far. I've seen a dozen videos and tried dozens of guides, and I hope you can help me; How to I make it so when I click the button, the corresponding entry in the database is deleted? Sorry that the code is a bit of a mess, right now, it is mostly strung together from old code and guides.

```
var database = firebase.database();


var ref = database.ref('Varer');
ref.on('value', gotData, errData);

function gotData(data){
    document.getElementById('Liste').innerHTML = "";
var kbdt = data.val();
var keys = Object.keys(kbdt);

for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++){


var k = keys[i];
var kob = kbdt[k].varer;


var btn  = document.createElement('button');
var btnText = document.createTextNode('Done')
  var opg = document.createElement('li');
  var opgnvn = document.createTextNode(kob);
  opg.appendChild(opgnvn);
  btn.appendChild(btnText); 
  opg.appendChild(btn);
  opg.setAttribute('id', k);
  opg.setAttribute('class', 'button');
  document.getElementById('Liste').append(opg);
  btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    deleteTask(this.id)});
}
}


function errData(err){
    console.log('error!');
    console.log(err);    
}

function deleteTask(id) {

console.log(id);




}


function Indkob() {
var nyVare = document.getElementById('tilfoj').value;
document.getElementById('Liste').innerHTML = "";
var data = {
    varer: nyVare
}
var result = ref.push(data);
console.log(result.keys);
}
```

Comment: Use `btn.addEventListener('click', deleteTask);`. Then use `function deleteTask(e) { console.log(e.target.id;) }`

Comment: Your code works if you add the `id` to the button instead: `btn.setAttribute('id', k);`

Comment: Thank you so much, thanks to you I figured it out, I can remove items now! I can't believe I was that close and yet so far away! Merry Christmas, Happy Holidays and a great big slobbering kiss!